# Where liquibase stores hash sums?

Tags: liquibase

When you apply changeSet to database, liquibase must store hashsum of that change.
Next time when you run your changelog, liquibase checks hashsum it saved yearlier with one , calculated based on changeSet from changelog.

If hashsums are different, then exception is raised.

Where is hashsum of changeSet is stored after applying it ?(and in what form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stored in the table named `databasechangelog`, in column named `MD5SUM`.